# How to select between the elements having a certain priority list?

Tags: java, algorithm, list, hashmap

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to write a method which will choose the best option in a list. Here is what I've got:

```
item_no      item_type      origin             
10               2             US
10               2             FR 
10               4             UK
11               6             FR
```

I put these in a list:

```
[[10, 2, US], [10, 2, FR], [10, 4, UK], [11, 6, FR]]
```

I will take this list in my method and I also have a specific item with some features. Let's choose my specific item as;

```
item_no   item_type   origin 
10           4            GE
```

Now, what I want to do is if one of the items in the list has a higher priority than my item, I will update my item's features with the higher priority item's features. The priority logic is respectively depends on `item_code`, `item_type` and `origin`. To get the priority order I'm using maps like below:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> itemCodeOrder = x.getItemCodeOrder();      
HashMap<String, Integer> itemTypeOrder = y.getItemTypeOrder(); 
HashMap<String, Integer> originOrder = z.getOriginOrder()
```

A typical priority order is like this:

- itemCodeOrder : 12, 10, 11
- itemTypeOrder : 6, 2, 4
- originOrder   : US, UK, FR, GE

In the first place I want to choose the higher priority item in the list and than compare that item with my item to update or not. For example, in the list above `item_no 10` has higher priority than `11`, so I will chose one of the items which has the `item_no 10`. Then, I will look at the `item_type`: I have `2` and `4`, now I'll choose one of the the item with `2`. So after looking the `origin`, I'll get `[10, 2, US]` in the end I'll compare it with my item and update is like:

```
 item_no   item_type   origin 
    10           2       US
```

I want to write a generic code but I couldn't find a proper way to get prior item in the list with my `HashMap` logic. How I can handle with this?

Comment: You can write items comparator and sort the list by priority. Then for the specific item just find whether the list has bigger priority.

Comment: As Stanislav commented, what you need is a good job for comparator. You can create it using your maps containing priority dictionaries as constructor arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, create a comparator, which would compare first by `code`, then by `type`, and finally by `origin`:

```
Comparator<Item> comparator = new Comparator<Item>() {

    Map<String, Integer> codes = x.getItemCodeOrder();      
    Map<String, Integer> types = y.getItemTypeOrder(); 
    Map<String, Integer> origins = z.getOriginOrder();

    @Override
    public int compare(Item a, Item b) {

        int byCode = Objects.requireNonNull(codes.get(a.code))
                       .compareTo(Objects.requireNonNull(codes.get(b.code)));

        if (byCode == 0) {
            int byType = Objects.requireNonNull(types.get(a.type))
                           .compareTo(Objects.requireNonNull(types.get(b.type)));

            if (byType == 0) {
                return Objects.requireNonNull(origins.get(a.origin))
                         .compareTo(Objects.requireNonNull(origins.get(b.origin)));

            } else 
                return byType;

        } else 
            return byCode;
    }
};
```

Then, sort your list of items:

```
Collections.sort(items, comparator);
```

The latest item in the list is now of the highest priority.

---

P.S. If you perform null-check on all list items before sorting, `Objects.requiresNonNull()` wrapping can be easily omitted.